# How to normalize data for weighted sum model

Tags: recommender-system, weights, z-score

I'm building a simple weighted sum model for ranking.

$$
\text{Store Rank} = w_1 \cdot param_1 + w_2 \cdot param_2 \ldots + w_n \cdot param_n
$$

The problem here is that one of the parameters depends on the type of another entity.

Let's say $param_2$ is a number of sales per month in an online store. It can be between 0 and 1000. However, those stores have different customer bases. Small stores have 8-10 customers, and big between 300-500. Small stores with 10-20 sales should have the same rank for this parameter as big stores with 300-400 sales.

One way is to calculate it as a ratio, e.g. $^\text{sales} / _\text{customers}$, but this is not an option in our case.

From what I have researched, $z\text{-score}$ might work here. However, I think our data is not normally distributed, and as I understand, it's not a good idea to use $z\text{-score}$ in this case. Shapiro test on our data is $0.8978014588356018$, and $P\text{-value}$ is $3.3320859960106475e-10$. Sample size is 1400.

Is it still ok to use a $z\text{-score}$, or there are better methods for this?

Comment: Your objective is not clear: what is your ranking intended to reflect about the stores?

Comment: We are going to use this rank to sort "stores" that are shown to customers: stores with larger rank will be considered more relevant to the end user

Comment: What quantitative data about end user relevance do you plan to use for finding the weights?

Comment: For now we are going to keep it simple with a two parameters: number of sales (which should be normalized somehow), and avg. rating of store (5 star rating from sales). We might add new parameters in the future

Comment: Right: but what data do you have about the *relevance?*  It seems you are trying to estimate or predict that with your weighted sums, but unless you have data, you're just making up the answer arbitrarily.

Comment: Do you mean that we don't know, if customers are going to find this score relevant when making a choice? We don't know this yet. I tried to analyze data to find correlations on which stores customers choose, and seems like there are none of them (via correlation matrix). But this is a formula with which business wants to start with. Because we are having a problem where customers don't know what to choose, so we want to help them.

Comment: Statistics offers nothing to inform customers about what they might like to buy: look to psychologists and market research for that advice.  When you don't have relevant information, it won't magically appear through some kind of statistical analysis.

Comment: I don't understand why I can't use my formula for ranking? And I didn't ask to find what parameters will work best with model. For us, it's fine to potentially going wrong with model. We don't have dataset and rankings just yet, and want to build MVP. That's what was my question about. Is having dataset for parameters that customers find useful is crucial for the question?

Comment: If you just want to make up a formula, certainly you can.  What it means and how reliable it might be for anything would seem to be questionable.  But, as far as I can tell--perhaps I haven't understood what you write--it looks like you haven't really asked a statistical question, because building a model out of nothing but what you think customers might find useful seems more a matter of psychology than statistics.

Comment: My question was just about how to scale parameter properly, so it gives fair score for different magnitude value of the parameter. However as I think now it's probably not a statistical question.

Comment: It seems you want to use as an [tag:recommender-system], you could look into that tag, and maybe add it to this post!